# How to apply chi square formula if the expected value is 0?

Tags: noise, white-noise

My $H_0$ hypothesis is that the N signals I've collected are just white random noise, i.e.:

$H_0: d(t) = n(t)$

I'm then asked to formulate the $\chi^2$ test for this. But according to the formula

$\chi^2 = \sum (O-E)^2/E$

But doesn't that mean, that the expected value going to be 0 for white noise normal distribution, hence I'd need to divide by zero?

Comment: Are you sure the $E$ in that formula is what you think it is? In the Pearson Chi-Squared test, it would be the expected *number* of occurrences of a class. Not the expectation of the noise.

Comment: Ohh I see, you're right. So how can I construct a test having not been given any observed data?

Comment: the $O$ is observed data, right?

Comment: Yes (adding words for the minimum length of a comment)